# Compatible notion of degree for $z^k : S^1 \to S^1$, when $k$ is not an integer?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

I'm thinking about degree as the induced map on the first homology groups - the degree of $z^k$ is $k$, when $k$ is an integer. What happens when $k$ is not an integer? Is there a compatible notion of degree, taking values in $\mathbb{C}$?

(My complex analysis is not that developed yet, so maybe this is a stupid question.)

Answer (score 3):

When $k$ is not an integer, then there is not a continuous map "$z^k$" from $S^1\to S^1$.

Comment: That's true, but that doesn't meant that there isn't a compatible notion... this is a soft question.

Comment: @user54092 Well, it's not at all clear what you're looking for for "compatible notion".

Comment: @MikeMiller something which has "degree" $k$ on $z^k$, for any $k$... I don't know what that would look like, which is why I asked here.

Comment: @MikeMiller And presumably well defined with respect to some weaker form of homotopy - such as: continuous deformations in $I$, but not in $S^1$. Although I'm not sure if that particular definition would be of much use.

Comment: @user54092 How do you propose we define the maps $z^k$?

Comment: @MikeMiller Well, there is certainly an issue there too, what with the multiple branches and all... for rational $k$, these functions are still locally continuous, right? I've heard (vaguely) that there are ways to construct domains on which multi-valued functions are less pathological (or whatever), and presumably in that context one could just use degree theory for differential manifolds. (Provided that the domain could be compactified or something.) But this is all very vague territory for me, so I was hoping that someone would have a more concrete answer.

Comment: @user54092: You can define a map "z^k" from $\mathbb{R}$, the universal cover of $S^1$ (a helix above the circle) to $S^1$, and then count how many times the image goes around the circle if you make one revolution in the helix $\mathbb{R}$. For $z^k$, it is exactly $k$, as you would expcet. In general, homology theory for multiple-valued functions might be interesting but I have no idea..

Comment: @PeterFranek How are you "counting" the number of times the image goes around for non-integer k? (Is $z^k$ lifting to a smooth path? Could I count by measuring the length of the path?)

Comment: Yes, if you consider it to be a map $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ (lift of $S^1$) to $S^1$ you can measure the length of the path (in the image) from $f(0)$ to $f(2\pi)$ and divide it by $2\pi$ (under the convenction that the circumference of the target $S^1$ is $2\pi$). At least I think so.